# emacs inf-ruby-console-auto "no such file or directory, bundle"

Tags: ruby, emacs, bundle

I am new to emacs and am trying to run M-x inf-ruby-console-auto and I get this error. Is there some configuration I am missing? I have bundle installed and I can't seem to find anything on this using google.

Comment: This command is meant to be used inside a project (several types are supported). If you just want to launch an interactive console, type `M-x inf-ruby`.

Comment: @Dmitry, I have a (rather large) rails project I'm trying to launch it inside. Do I need to have a certain file open in within the project for it to work?

Comment: No, the project contents just have to satisfy a few conditions. See the definition of `inf-ruby-console-rails-p`, for Rails projects. It's not a Rails 2 project, by any chance?

Comment: @Dmitry, no its rails 3. I don't have the command `inf-ruby-console-rails-p` only `inf-ruby-console-rails`

Comment: It's not a command, it's a function. If you don't have it, you should update to the latest version of `inf-ruby`.

Comment: Non-interactive function, to be precise. Commands are also functions.

Comment: So I actually got it to work, I forgot to install rvm.el so my Gemfile wasn't being loaded properly. Restarted emacs and it stopped working again :(

Comment: Duh, of course. I don't know why I thought you have some different problem. Regarding rvm.el, you probably need to enable it in your init file.

Comment: So I got the console starting up, but now its it can't find the rake gem and to run bundle install to install it. When I run the rails process outside of emacs I don't get any of these problems. Any idea what this might be?

Comment: Wrong Ruby version, or wrong gemspec, if you use them.

Comment: Finally got it working!! Thanks for all the help :D

Comment: @Dmitry : you should make your first comment the answer. Sill useful.

Comment: @Dmitri Did it really help you? This exact error message usually means that the user has problems with it Ruby version manager setup (rbenv, rvm, etc), and that the wrong version is being called (one without bundler installed).

Comment: @yes it did! Trying to starting inf-ruby, you have a choice of several consoles, including "default" and "auto." Kept trying different ones, but forgot that all you need is `inf-ruby`. The error brought me here, as this is the top search result for it. If you do make it an answer, you could add a note about other problems this error indicates.